# My webpage getting redirected to the hosting site when someone enters a partially wrong URL

Tags: php, web, hosting

I have hosted my site in 000webhost.com in the free tier.

When I'm pressing "xyz.com/abc" instead of "xyz.com/abc.php" it's getting redirected to 000webhost.com site.

Anyways to prevent it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that would be redirected to the Error Page as there is no such file called "abc" ( You can create a file named only "abc", think of Linux systems).

**Three** ways to solve this:

1)Alongside abc.php, also **create a directory** named "abc" and keep the same abc.php page with index.php . This will load the same page( but at a different location).

*WARNING: If you have used relative paths in your code,Beware! May cause address resolution problems.*

2) You can try using **redirection features**, if that is available with the free tier. As far I know, that is available in the professional cPanel provided by standard hosting services. But for 000webhost, I cannot vouch that.

3)Create a **sub-domain** "abc" and keep all the necessary files there too. This may sound redundant but will overcome the Warning associated with the 1st point.

Comment: Yah that's true I can add "abc" as a file name but I want to know whether the redirection feature is available in free hosting and if it's there how to find it?

Comment: Yes! You can add redirects in the free tier of 000webhost. 
Go to -> Advanced -> Redirects -> Set up the target and destination addresses 
And Voila! You are all set :)

Comment: Can it be applied to subdomain's also? I can see it for only domains